# Using webSocket for the first time (in React) and I get, "failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm following the documentation but I get 'failed: Error in connection establishment' and can't figure out why.

```
    class App extends React.Component {
    
       ws = new WebSocket("ws:https://sampleserver.com");
    
      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.ws.onopen = () => {
          // on connecting, do nothing but log it to the console
          console.log('connected',this.ws)
          }
this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
        // listen to data sent from the websocket server
        const message = JSON.parse(evt.data)
        this.setState({dataFromServer: message})
        console.log(message)
        }

        this.ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
        // automatically try to reconnect on connection loss

        }
       }
```

Comment: Change `ws:https://sampleserver.com` to `ws://sampleserver.com`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been working at this for a while and it's always frustrating/reliving when the error is so simple.